# SgmlLinkExtractor in scrapy

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy, rules, extractor

i need some enlightenment about SgmlLinkExtractor in scrapy.

For the link: **example.com/YYYY/MM/DD/title** i would write:

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/\w+']), callback='parse_example')]
```

For the link: **example.com/news/economic/title** should i write:

`r'\news\category\w+'`or `r'\news\w+/\w+'` ? (**category** changes but the url contains always **news**)

For the link: **example.com/article/title** should i write:

`r'\article\w+'` ? (the url contains always **article**)

Comment: You should improve your question. It is missing what does not work with the code. Because it looks fine and should do what you want.

Comment: You don't need to add "i need help" or "Please HELP" to your questions. Everybody asking a question does so. To increase the chance of getting a good answer it's better to compile a good question. (what have you done, what do you expect, what do you get, ... see FAQ for more information)

Comment: ok sorry, it's just because i have only 5 days to do that... i 'll edit the message. @FrankMartin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to answer "should i" questions if you don't provide complete example strings and what you want to match (and what you don't want to match) with a regular expression.

I guess, that your regex won't work because you use `\` instead of `/`.

I recommend you go to [regex101](http://regex101.com) and test if your urls match your regular expressions. See following screenshot:

[image]